# Is it possible to have a UITableViewController hide its cells until there's content, and in the meantime display a "no content" message?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

Similar to how Apple did it in their music app:

[image]

I want to have a `UITableViewController`, but how would I best go about only showing the cells if there's content, otherwise show that "no content" message. Just put a `UIView` on top of the table view?

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Design a **no content view** (UIView) as you wish, add that view to self.view and position it on top of your table view. Make it hidden initially. Then inside `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method, you can do something like this.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int count = songsArray.count;

    if(count==0){
        self.noContentView.hidden = NO;
    }else{
        self.noContentView.hidden = YES;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could count tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:, and add a subview (which is your empty view, eg: an imageView or a UILabel ) depend of your `count`.

eg, create a custom "empty" label in your viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   _emptyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
   _emptyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   // add en empty notes image placholder
   // when there is no data to display
   _emptyNoteImageView         = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((self.view.bounds.size.width) / 3), 50, 119, 120)];
   _emptyNoteImageView.image   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_empty_images"];

   _emptyLabel                 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((self.view.bounds.size.width) / 5), self.view.bounds.size.width - 150, 200, 20)];
   _emptyLabel.text            = @"No note to display";
   _emptyLabel.font            = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12.0f];
   _emptyLabel.textAlignment   = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   _emptyLabel.textColor       = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
   _emptyLabel.shadowColor     = [UIColor whiteColor];
   _emptyLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   [_emptyView addSubview:_emptyLabel];
}
```

and then, depend on your numberOfRowsInSection count, you can add/remove it to/from self.view.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    count = [self.dataSource count];

    if (count > 0) {
        [_emptyView removeFromSuperview];
    } else {
        [self.view addSubview:_emptyView];
    }

    return count;
}
```

Or simply put, you could use this category...
https://github.com/nxtbgthng/UITableView-NXEmptyView

-- Hope it help you!

Comment: I appreciate going the extra mile and showing an example of constructing the UI elements.

Comment: This should have more upvotes. Not that I only like that you took the time to create a working example, the linked library is a superb addition. I use it in most of my projects. +1

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you are populating your UITableView using a NSMUtableArray ("array").

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     UIView *noDataView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];

     UILabel *noDataLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,50)];
     [noDataLabel setText:@"No Data Found"];
     [noDataView addSubview:noDataLabel];

     [noDataView setHidden:TRUE];

     array=[self fetchDataIntoArray];

     if([array count]==0)
     {
          noDataView.hidden=FALSE;
          [self.view bringSubviewToFront:noDataView];

          self.tableView.hidden = TRUE;
     }
     else
     {
          self.tableView.hidden=FALSE;
          [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];

          noDataView.hidden = TRUE;
     }

}
```